# how to define an input in Entity with 2D-array?

Tags: vhdl

i want to define an input with `2D` array in an entity how can i make that

i tried to define a `d` input by this code

```
ENTITY ShRegister IS
  port(
    clk,rst:in std_logic;
    d:in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    q:out std_logic
    );
END ENTITY ShRegister;
```

But Not Working

Comment: i fount the answer .. Writing it for Knowledge

    `PACKAGE BUFFON IS
        type input_arrray_t is array (3 downto 0,0 to 3) of INTEGER RANGE -15 to 15;
    END PACKAGE BUFFON;
    
    ENTITY ShRegister IS
      port(
        clk,rst:in std_logic;
        d:in BUFFON;
        q:out std_logic
        );
    END ENTITY ShRegister;`

hope it's understood

Comment: You should answer your own question and accept the answer then ;)